# Differentiation under the integration sign on manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

For an oriented manifold $M$ with rank n, a compactly supported n-form $\omega$ and a family of diffeomorphisms $\psi_t:M \rightarrow M$, ($t\in R$) consider the function $f(t)=\int_M \psi_t^*\omega$. ($\psi_t^*$ being the pullback of  $\psi_t$).
Under what conditions is it true that $f'(t)=\int_M \frac{\delta}{\delta t}\psi_t^*\omega$ ?

Comment: What is $*$? Multiplication, convolution, pushforward, or pullback?

Comment: It is the pullback.

Comment: You should write it $\psi_{t }^*$

Comment: Also I suspect that answer is going to be precisely when you may do so in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Choose an oriented atlas for your manifold and find a partition of unity subordinate to the coordinate cover. In each coordinate neighborhood you will be homeomorphic (indeed diffeomorphic) to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the usual rules will apply.